# Colorbox: DON't close #colorbox on click within #colorbox inside #cboxOverlay

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I use Colorbox plugin in Bootstrap project. For responsive corrections I appended #colorbox div inside #cboxOverlay. It's works fine , BUT when clicking #colorbox itself, popup is closed.

How can I stop closing #colorbox on clicking within #colorbox, it should be closed only on click parent #cboxOverlay.

My code is :

Create colorbox on click "getaddress" button

```
$(".getaddress").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "100%", maxWidth: "620px", closeButton: false, 
                                onComplete: function () {
                                $('body').addClass("modal-open");
                                },
                                onClosed: function () {
                                $('body').removeClass("modal-open");
                                },

    });
```

Append #colorbox to #cboxOverlay

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $("#colorbox").appendTo("#cboxOverlay");
});
```

Comment: can you create a snippet with html code too?

Comment: I have already solved this one, thanks a lot for comment, can you please advise with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673941/colorbox-colorbox-not-changing-width-to-fit-screen-while-changing-landscape-fr