# Colorbox: #colorbox not changing width to fit screen while changing Landscape from Portrait on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, colorbox

Please advise asap! I'm struggling with Colorbox and have issue on mobile orientation change. When I open colorbox popup on portrait and change to landscape it works ok, but when I open on landscape and change to portrait, the width is not changing.

I don't want scroll inside popup, I make body to scroll if colorbox height is higher. See code in this question [Colorbox: DON't close #colorbox on click within #colorbox inside #cboxOverlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671562/colorbox-dont-close-colorbox-on-click-within-colorbox-inside-cboxoverlay)

Comment: Same, can you create a snippet with the code so I can try to help?